# Fridge Thermostat Replacement - Terminals Differ. Wiring Help - RLA36G.1 (UK)

Tags: thermostat, refrigerator

****TL;DR:** Can this be wired up to work?**

[image][image][image]
[image]
More images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u41xh.jpg
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JzcEI.jpg)[image]

(You can't tell because of the flash--but the two browns that connect next to each other on the thermostat are just slightly different shades.)

One comes from inside the fridge and the other from the light switch. Darker on the right, lighter brown on the left.

The 2 brown wires that go at section 3 only has 1 terminal here.

And single black cable that goes at 4 has two terminals.

I've tried looking for my exact model, but they all seem to be this type with alt terminals.

---

Story:
(The fridge is acting up. Originally it was getting far too cold on 3(n) dial setting--that is normally fine for this time of year. I had to turn it to 1.5 to reach ideal temps. Move over a few weeks and now it's the opposite. It isn't getting cold enough, although it still frosts at the top back.)

It seems to sound like the compressor is always on. It's quite random. Ice is melting atm. Very random.

Since I need a fridge pronto..I chanced buying a replacement thermostat. I don't think that's the issue, but it's worth a try I suppose. Only I've opened the package, and my fridge only to notice it differs slightly.

What do I do? Thanks.

(UK)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not seeing why it won't just match, pin for pin.
Both have a clearly matching earth, the lives seem to be on a double-adapted spade terminal [it may be one piece of metal made for two wires, or one of the spades also has a tab the second spade goes onto - either way, they're a pair & move as such] & the neutral uses one tab [of which the spare was originally clipped.]
It just looks like the replacement could cover more than one model, it's not been trimmed to fit only that fridge. The numbers even match, what we can see of them. You could use either earth tab, or either of the pins 4. They're electrically equivalent.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. 

That's why I am asking. I don't know. If I match everything up exactly I'm still left with a spare brown cable, because originally two brown spades go to 3. Just to confirm --what you're saying is I can put one on 4 next to the black?

I'll take another picture with the spades off completely.

Comment: Sorry, was afk for a day. I see you've figured it out now. The brown is a 'double' plug that fits onto a single tab. The black & green just have one more equivalent tab on the new model… but of course you must match black to one of those 2 terminals numbered 4 & the green must go on one of the terminals on the external casing.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. It's all because I didn't take it out and it was at night. It looked like two tabs.

The wiring is of course, but the main issue isn't resolved. The fridge still doesn't get cold enough and the compressor is on all the time.

Comment: "The fridge still doesn't get cold enough"  -  Are both the freezer side and the frig side not cold enough?  Looking for detailed observations like that will help you diagnose the problem.   It could be something easy like ice blocking the evaporator.  Or something expensive, like no refrigerant in the copper lines.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the replies.

I assumed both browns were linked but it really didn't look like it. It genuinely looked like the thermostat has two terminals on 3. I was wrong. All because I'm doing it at night with less than ideal lighting, and because I didn't fully take the thermostat out to be able to remove that brown cable.

Haha. Idiot moment.
[image]
[image]

Comment: No....  a learning moment.

Comment: +1 for sharing your "moment" with the rest of us.

Comment: It's only been fitted for a few hours. I'm not sure that solved it. I'll find out in the morning after leaving it overnight.

The wiring is solved but the actual issue probably isn't.

Comment: Since you haven't yet taken the [tour], I'll remind you to please be sure to give an up vote to [Tetsujin's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/244687/34147) since he's the one who suggested this solution to you (if you haven't already). It's nice to give credit where credit is due.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone can say whether this can be hacked to work.

Correct replacement parts should have the same connections.  It is supposed to be plug and play, no hacks.  Are you sure the vendor gave you the correct part?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Yeah, that's what I thought, so I didn't bother to compare the terminals prior to ordering.  

But as Tetsujin said, it seems to be a replacement that covers a lot of models?

I ordered from: 
https://www.ransomspares.co.uk/parts/brands/hotpoint/fridges-freezers/rla36g.1%20(869991555680)/thermostat/30329.htm

But looking around it's the only type I can find that is indeed listed as comparable with loads of models.

I can't even find a perfect match.